# uncompress .Z file in C

Tags: c, compression

Can someone point me to a public domain (or MIT- or BSD-license) library for decompressing .Z files in ANSI C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I was talking rubbish in my previous response. Apparently unix compressed files (.Z) use LZW, not Deflate.

In this case, check out [liblzw](http://freestdf.sourceforge.net/liblzw.php). It is public domain.

Answer (score 0):

There's a public domain version on sourceforge: [ncompress](http://ncompress.sourceforge.net/)

**Edit:** [liblzw](http://freestdf.sourceforge.net/liblzw.php) (DrJokepu's suggestion) and ncompress share the same developer and codebase, so stick with liblzw...

Answer (score 0):

You can use BSD-licensed library [lzws](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws). It has no legacy code from ncompress (20 century).